# iPhone 6S storage issue

Tags: iphone

I have iOS devices since the 3GS but this happened to me for the first time tonight.. I have the 16GB model. It's quite enough for me. I had 2.2GB free. This afternoon I performed 3 updates and 2 hours after that my storage started declining and went to 0 bytes. Since then it stack 0 bytes for no reason. Any opinions?

Comment: What updates did you perform?

Comment: Etsy, maps.me, Twitter, flipboard, ipgmail

Comment: Only app updates? No iOS upgrades or anything like that?

Comment: No. I have the latest version since it came out.. I am chatting with Apple Support now...

Comment: Try taking a look at `Settings -> General -> Storage & iCloud Usage -> Manage Storage`. This should give you an idea to what is using your space.

Comment: Zach I checked all that myself and again with Apple Support but if you add all that I should have 2.2GB free.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've talked with Apple Support, and they determined that it is probably a software glitch. The only solution is a reinstallation of iOS.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting the iPhone will clear temporary files and caches. That should clear up anything that was left over from the updates you've performed.

You can force a restart by holding the home button and the sleep/wake button simultaneously for 10 seconds until the device powers off.

Comment: I tried that before posting but didn't work...

Comment: Temporary files and caches will certainly not account for 2.2GB of missing space. Also, why force a restart instead of a normal restart?

Comment: Because a normal restart will re-load everything that was stored in memory before the restart. A forced restart clears it.
https://discussions.apple.com/thread/2467216?start=0&tstart=0